# Can't access Active Directory Web Services via PowerShell

Tags: active-directory

I have set up a test lab consisting of two 2012 R2 servers. One is a domain controller (srv1), the other a member server (srv2).

When looking at 'netstat -ano | findstr 9389' i can see a service is listing on the ADWS port - i have disabled the firewall an all profiles for testing purposes. So far so good...

However when trying to do some queries from srv2 using e.g 'Get-AdUser' the connection times out and the cmdlet throws an exception:

```
get-aduser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist,     it is currently down, or it does not have the ADWS running....
```

I have tried to do a poor-mans portscan using 'telnet srv1 9389' which also times out. So this must be network related in some way. I can use 'Get-AdUser' on the domain controller itself.

Any hints on this? TIA

Comment: can you ping srv1 from srv2 using the FQDN of srv1?   FQDN = Fully Qualified Domain Name or srv1.sub.domain.suffix.   It could be something as simple as a DNS issue.   Are you able to login to the domain without any issues from srv2?   Does the login take a long time to complete?

Comment: login doesn't take exceptionally long, i gues it's a dns issue as a well... i will test this evening. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Answer is in the error:

Is the DC/GC you’re running the process on have the ADWS running and is it contactable?

ADWS is also a single feature if you want to go back and check it's installed...